# How can I print all elements of an array (passed as props from the parent's state) inside JSX code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, foreach, jsx

I am new to React and I am trying to navigate the JSX syntax, combined with state/ props and pure Javascript.

I am passing props from the parent component (App) to the child component (Character). One of the props is an array of numbers which I am trying to print to the page, inside a paragraph, when the child component gets rendered. I figured it out how to print all other props (which are either strings or numbers) but I can't find a solution for the seasons array. I can print all the elements of the array to the console using a forEach loop but I have no idea how to integrate the result into JSX. I would like for the last paragraph of the child component to read

Seasons: 1, 2, 3

or how many numbers the array has.

EDIT: I would like for each printed season to be a separate element (a link for example) and not to transform the array into a single string which reads "1, 2, 3" (like when using join(,).

Here is my code for the App component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Characters from './Characters'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      characters: [
        {
          screenName: "Uhtred Uhtredson",
          description: "Uthred's younger son, originally named Osbert.",
          realName: "Alexander Dreymon",
          seasons: [1, 2, 3],
          id: 1
        },
        {
          screenName: "Brida",
          description: "Former lover of Uhtred. Ally to Ragnall Ivarsson. Lady of Dunholme and widow to Ragnar.",
          realName: "Emily Cox",
          seasons: [1, 2, 3],
          id: 2
        },
        {
          screenName: "King Edward",
          description: "King Alfred's son and King of Wessex.",
          realName: "Timothy Innes",
          seasons: [1, 2, 3],
          id: 3
        }
      ]

    }
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <Characters theCharacters={this.state.characters} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

And this is the code for the Character component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Characters = (props) => {

    // we use destructuring by storing the array of objects into the characters const
    const { theCharacters } = props;

    const charactersList = theCharacters.map(character => {
        return (
            <div className="character" key={character.id}>
                <p>On screen name: {character.screenName}</p>
                <p>Short description: {character.description}</p>
                <p>Real name: {character.realName}</p>
                <p>Apparitions: {

                    character.seasons.forEach(season => {
                         return season; //this here doesn't do anything
                        //console.log(season);
                    })}</p>
            </div>
        )
    })

        return (
          <div className="character_list">
            {charactersList}
         </div>
              )
    }

export default Characters;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything. You should use `map`.

```
{ 
  character.seasons.map(season => <p>{season}</p>)
}
```

Comment: Thx. This solution makes the most sense since I am trying to print my seasons as individual items and not all in one string.

Answer (score 3):

`character.seasons.join(',')` it takes array elements and returns string, comma is a separator

Comment: @Bartosz  thank you, I just edited my question, I wasn't clear about it. I don't want for the array to be converted into a string, I want to print each individual element/ season (maybe as link, for example) separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you render an array of JSX elements, they'll render just fine; so you can just map the array of values to an array of JSX elements. Note that in these cases, it's important for each element to have a unique key that cannot change for that element, even if it moves positions in the array, to help React render them properly. Luckily, you already have an ID for each character you can use :)

So in your case, you can do something like this:

```
return (
  <div className="character_list">
    {charactersList.map(character => (
      <span key={character.id}>{character.screenName}</span>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

And of course you can render more than just the screenName however you want in there.